# Crystal date based record selection; no lower date through Saturday

Tags: crystal-reports, date-range

I want to set up a Crystal report with a default date range for record selection.  I want the date range to be no lower date through Saturday of the current week based on the formula field {@Calc Promise Date}.  I am a lighter end user of Crystal and am having trouble with this.

I can use:

{@Calc Promise Date} in AllDatesToToday

But I am looking for a way to have the results be all dates to Saturday of the current week.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help from Siva on a similar question, I now have the answer for this one.
Make a new Formula Field of "End Date" that contains:

```
if DayOfWeek (DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate))) = 1
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate)+6)
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate))) = 2
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate)+5)
else if  DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate))) = 3
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate)+4)
else if  DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate))) = 4
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate)+3)
else if  DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate))) = 5
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate)+2)
else if  DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate))) = 6
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate)+1)
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate))) = 7
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate)+0)
```

Then in Record Selection reference that formula.  In my case, the correlating date range for the records was a Through Current Date Range formula field, so my Record Selection was then updated to include the following line:

```
{@Through Current Date Range}<{@End Date}
```

Comment: Actually <= {@End Date}